# Calculating the class number for fundamental discriminants -8 and 5

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

I know only the following facts about binary quadratic forms: for a non-square determinant $D$ with $D \equiv 1$ or $0$ mod 4 all equivalence classes of forms with discriminant  $D$ have a reduced form with coeffiecients $a,b,c$ such that $|b| \leq |a| \leq |c|$. For $D<0$, $|a| \leq \sqrt{|D|/3}$. Whereas for $D>0$ we have $|a| \leq \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{D}$. Which gives a bound for $b$ using the very first inequality. This in turn, allows $c$ to be determined, through the discriminant formula, once $a,b$ are chosen.

As for my specific question: for $h(5)$ resp. $h(-8)$. I believe there is only one equivalence class (that of $f(x,y)=x^2+xy-y^2$ resp. $x^2+2y^2$).

Is there any clever, elementary way to verify my claim other than brute force checking all forms whose coefficients satisfy the inequalities and then reducing and comparing the reduced forms?

Comment: I think you made an error, it should read $|b| \leq \sqrt{|D|/3}$. Often one may rule out a lot of cases simply by working mod $2$, where $b^2 + 4ac = b \mod 2$.

Comment: Well, that's just a consequence of $|b|\leq |a|$. Would uou mind explaining a bit more about the trick with mod 2?

Comment: Ok yes, silly me. For example computing the reduced BQF's of discriminant $-23$ one sees $|b| \leq \sqrt{23/3} < 3$. Then when $b \equiv 0 \mod 2$ we have $b^2 + 4ac = 0 \mod 2$. So we only have to consider $b = 1$.

Comment: The form of discriminant $-8$ is $x^2+2y^2$ (you have $-$).

Comment: @roger Thank you. Yes.

Comment: @Mummy_the_turkey wouldn't this also work for $D\equiv b^2-4ac\equiv b$ mod 2?

Comment: @mummy technically, for $D=-23$ you need to consider $b=-1$ as well as $b=1$.  The forms $2x^2+xy+3y^2$ and $2x^2-xy+3y^2$ are not equivalent.